# Loading beans from Grails Script

Tags: grails, dependencies

I'm running a grails script to load a bean from the grails application, however, it seems that I have a dependency problem. Here it's my code:

```
import grails.spring.BeanBuilder
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext

target(main: "Script to load location information into Solr") {

println "Hello script"
def bb = new BeanBuilder()
ApplicationContext appContext = bb.createApplicationContext()
def service = appContext.getBean("solrjService")   
}

setDefaultTarget(main)
```

When I execute the script I get the following stacktrace:

```
main:
Hello script
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.GroovyStarter.rootLoader(GroovyStarter.java:108)
at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.GroovyStarter.main(GroovyStarter.java:130)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:120)
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access field org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder.SINGLETON from class org.slf4j.LoggerFactory
at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.staticInitialize(LoggerFactory.java:83)
at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.<clinit>(LoggerFactory.java:73)
at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.SLF4JLogFactory.getInstance(SLF4JLogFactory.java:155)
at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.SLF4JLogFactory.getInstance(SLF4JLogFactory.java:131)
at org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory.getLog(LogFactory.java:272)
at grails.spring.BeanBuilder.<clinit>(BeanBuilder.java:84)
```

Any ideas ??

Thanks for your time

Comment: I assume it's crashing on the way to tell you that there's no `solrjService` bean in your new, empty application context.

Comment: I need to load solrjService from this groovy script, so, how should I do it?? If I comment ApplicationContext appContext = bb.createApplicationContext()
and def service = appContext.getBean("solrjService") it still crashes. How can I see what dependencies conflict in a grails application?? (Probably I have to exclude some library in Buildconfig.groovy) thanks Burt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your read the call stack, it's obviously a problem with SLF4J.

See http://slf4j.org/faq.html#IllegalAccessError

It looks like you may be mixing versions of the SLF4J jars, and getting a conflict.

But, of course, Burt is correct - once you get past this, you will find that you've initialized you BeanBuilder's ApplicationContext with no beans.

Comment: which is the best way to find this jars? I know that they are in .ivy/cache directory (I can look there manually) but I wonder if there is an automatic way to do that (some tool...) thanks

Answer (score 1):

I had to include the target _GrailsBootstrap to be able to load my beans http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/commandLine.html#creatingGantScripts

```
includeTargets << grailsScript("_GrailsBootstrap")

target ('default': "Load Location Information to Solr Server") {

depends(configureProxy, packageApp, classpath, loadApp, configureApp)
def service = appCtx.getBean('solrjService')
println service.getLocationSuggestion("Barcelona")

}
```

I run script his way (that's why I had a classpath problem)

```
grails run-script scripts/Myscript.groovy
```

Then now, I run it this way

```
grails Myscript.groovy
```

and I don't have any classpath problems :D

thanks for your help